# Count character occurrences in a file

Tags: java, count

I want a short and efficient code of counting the occurence of different characters and numbers in a textfile. This one is only for one character.

Is there a way to this without giving every single character and number a charToSearch variable? Also without having an enormous ugly if statement.

```
public void countOccurence() {
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("somefile.txt"));
    int ch;
    char charToSearch='a';
    int counter=0;
    while((ch=reader.read()) != -1) {
        if(charToSearch == (char)ch) {
            counter++;
        }
    };
    reader.close();
    System.out.pritln("Character: " + charToSearch + " occurs " + counter + " times.");
}
```

Comment: Maybe something like a Map<Character, Integer> to store your character counts. It just maps a character to its corresponding count.

Comment: You currently have the best option actually

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a hashmap:

```
Map<Character, Integer> charMap = new HashMap<Character, Integer>();
while((ch=reader.read()) != -1) {
  char key = (char)ch;
  if(charMap.containsKey(key)) {
    int value = charMap.get(key);
    charMap.put(key, value + 1);
  } else {
     charMap.put(key,1);
  }
}
```

Comment: I ended up going with this. :) Good method, gets all characters including brackets, etc. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
public void countOccurence() {

   for(Character ch :"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789".toCharArray())
        {
             BufferedReader reader
                         = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("somefile.txt"));
             int ch;
             char charToSearch=ch;
             int counter=0;
             while((ch=reader.read()) != -1) {
                   if(charToSearch == (char)ch) {
              counter++;
          }
        };
        reader.close();
        System.out.pritln("Character: " + charToSearch + " occurs " + counter 
        + " times.");

             }
        }
```

Comment: That char array was exactly the kind of thing I needed. Gonna try it, thanks!

Comment: Your welcome, and do mark the answer as right if it works for you :)